# Как почистить консоль хрома?

Tags: google-chrome

Здраствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой в консоле вылазят какие-то непонятные ошибки и я не знаю как их убрать[image: введите сюда описание изображения](ссылки замазал, так как забочусь о своей безопасности)

Comment: `console.clear()` не?

Comment: А если выделить ошибку мышкой и перевести через любой онлайн переводчик?

Comment: Ты что на сервере или хостинге запускаешь майнинг? Таких обычно хостинговые компании банят))

Comment: console.clear() пробовал, но при обновлении страницы всё вылазит заново

Comment: мне нужно убрать это) а не понять из-за чего это)